# Spring RestTemplate receiving sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Tags: java, spring, https, resttemplate

I'm trying to connect to a third party URL that is over HTTPS. They told us that all we need is to send them a HTTPS POST (no certificates/keystore required). However, I'm receiving the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://mep.moxtra.com/sample/api/v1/auth/cus/token": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
... 33 more

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
... 56 more
```

This is the code I have and I managed to implement some of the approaches to allow Spring RestTemplate make a POST to a HTTPS API.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(buildCustomRequestFactory());
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
//This will only add the parameters I need on the body to call the POST operation
MultiValueMap<String, String> parametersMap = buildParametersMap(hubUserInfo);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> jsonRequestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>>(parametersMap, requestHeaders);
try {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(moxtraApiUrl, jsonRequestEntity, String.class);

    System.out.println(response.getBody());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For the creation of the CustomRequestFactory:

```
private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory buildCustomRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    return requestFactory;
}
```

Do you know if I am missing some configuration or there's another approach to achieve making the POST request over HTTPS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you perform the https call not via code (using curl or postman for example)? In addition, are you running an anti-virus or some network security software? If so, try disabling it temporarily and see if the code works

Comment: thanks for the answer. I made the call via postman and it worked. I'm working on a MAC with no security software installed.

Comment: OK, and what happens if you are not using the custom client (creating the rest template with: `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()`)?

Comment: same exception comes up. I did at first without adding the custom client.

Comment: What is the version of the JVM running your code? if you can, try using the latest version available

Comment: Well I am working with Java 8 since it is the standard for the company right now and yes, it is the latest version.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the SSL certificate - the certificate chain is incomplete. There are several tools to test SSL certificates, for example look at [this one](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://mep.moxtra.com/). In this case you'll have to contact the API provider and ask them to fix the issue before you can securely make requests...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will check the page as well as communicate with the team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue of the SSLHandshakeException by adding some code to the method: `buildCustomRequestFactory`

Before that, I needed to create a class called `TrustAllStrategy` that implements the `TrustStrategy` interface from `org.apache.http.ssl`

It was as simple as doing this:

```
public class TrustAllStrategy implements TrustStrategy {
/**
 * Implement strategy to always trust certificates.
 * @see {org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy} TrustStrategy
 */
@Override
public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
    return true;
}

}
```

Then I modified the method `buildCustomRequestFactory`:

```
public static HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory buildCustomRequestFactory(String host, int port) throws MoxtraSingleSignOnProcessException {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = null;
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = null;
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = null;
        NoopHostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier = new NoopHostnameVerifier();
        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

    try {
        sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy()).useProtocol(SecurityConstants.TLS_V_12).build();
        sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostNameVerifier);
        clientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register(SecurityConstants.HTTPS, sslSocketFactory)
                .register(SecurityConstants.HTTP, PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()).build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager clientConnectionMgr = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
        HttpHost customHttpHost = new HttpHost(host, port);
        clientConnectionMgr.setSocketConfig(customHttpHost, SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIME_OUT).build());

        httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(clientConnectionMgr).build();
        requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MoxtraSingleSignOnProcessException("A problem occured when tried to setup SSL configuration for API call", e);
    }

    return requestFactory;
}
```

Host and port values are from the service provider. Then I created a context configured to use TLSv1.2 (since this is the one I was told to use by the provider).

After that I added some registry configurations for HTTPS and HTTP and just configured the connection manager object to have a Socket Time Out.

With that I was able to make a call to the service.

Also the Rest Template object creation changed to pass the parameters:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(buildCustomRequestFactory(host, port));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helps me.

Comment: Thanks for the post, helped me in fixing the issue.

Comment: Hardcode trust is a very bad practice and security issue.

Comment: How to fix this when the URL is provided at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem implementing the Resttemplate configuration of this baeldung tutorial. It's simple.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

```
@Value("${trust.store}")
private Resource trustStore;

@Value("${trust.store.password}")
private String trustStorePassword;

@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
     SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
          .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray())
          .build();
     SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new 
             SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
     HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                             .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                             .build();
     HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = 
                              new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
return new RestTemplate(factory);
```

}

In the application.properties add:

```
#trust store location
trust.store=classpath:certificate-example.p12
#trust store password
trust.store.password=yourpassword
```

I hope can helpful.